# :: TypeError: _this3.feedbackform is not a function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Why this error come in react when i call another function in `componentDidUpdate` for call another api this error comes : TypeError: _*this3.feedbackform* is not a function?

```
    fetch(baseurl + 'submitform/register', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: data,
    }).then((res) => {
        return res.json();
    }).then((data) => {
        console.log(data);
        if (data.code == 200) {
            alert(data.message);
            this.feedbackform.bind(this);
        } else if (data.code == 405) {
            alert(data.message);
        }
        /* this.setState({
                loaded: true,
                response: data.response
         })*/
        //   console.log(this.State.resp);
    });


    feedbackform()
    {
        alert('Feedback');
    }
```

Comment: Please include a code snippet that reproduces your error

Comment: bind feedbackform function  inside of constructor

Comment: I tried bind inside constructor also ,but it is not working

Comment: Can anyone tell how to do this.